# Export html table contents as xlsx format

Tags: php, html, excel, export-to-excel, xlsx

Iam using PHP+jQuery to export the html table contents. When I click on on export button, the excel file is generated successfully as xls format. I want to generate the file as xlsx format.

```
$FileName="my-file.xls";
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$FileName.'');
header("Pragma: ");
header("Cache-Control: ");
echo $_REQUEST['tableData'];
exit();
```

Adding the jQuery

```
var clone_val = $(".tblExport").clone();
$("#tData").val($('<span><style> .textFormat {  mso-number-format:"\@"; } .numberFormat { mso-number-format:"0\.00" }</style>').append (clone_val).html());
$("#excel-export-form").submit();
```

The table contents is stored inside a input box having attribute `id="tData" name="tableData"` using jQuery. 
When I changed the filename as `my-file.xlsx`, a corrupted xlsx file is generated. Also tried Data Table excel export, but it didn't support multiple headers.

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958282/php-generate-xlsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a php library. I prefer [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) to use for working with excel.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to do with the current code. Now xls is export is working.

Comment: I think exporting xlsx without PhpSpreadSheet is very difficult and I suggest to you using this library.